# Can we add checkboxes and print button on custom record’s list page?

Tags: netsuite, suitescript2.0

Is it possible to add checkboxes and print button on custom record’s list page?  I want to select some records and print pdf for them.

I tried by creating custom list suitelet. but I want to add on standard list. Is there any way to achieve this? Please help!